# padding spaces at right while writing data frame to fwf

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, fixed-width

I am writing Pandas Data Frame to a fixed width file using numpy. Here is my code.

```
with open(self.tablePath,mode) as ofile:
   np.savetxt(ofile, tdata.values, fmt='%4s%12s%15s')
```

This code adds the spaces to the left side of every column values. How do I padding the spaces at the right side of the every column values?
I get the result as following,

```
xxxx        yyyy         256.25
xxx1      yyyyy1         430.25
```

But I want my result as follows,

```
xxxxyyyy        256.25         
xxx1yyyyy1      430.25
```

Comment: Can you add what you are getting now, and what is it you are looking for, it is not very clear what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an old C programmer I remember that minus (`-`) means right padding. You just need:

```
with open(self.tablePath,mode) as ofile:
   np.savetxt(ofile, tdata.values, fmt='%-4s%-12s%-15s')
```

Comment: Thank you :) It works. And also I want to know if there is any pythonic way to do this? Your answer is correct for my question. So I check the correct answer :)

Comment: @SmithDwayne: What do you call *a pythonic way* here? This way correctly uses Numpy, so I cannot see any problem...